# Create and get dynamic variable with php

Tags: php, mysql

i know this question probably been asked and answered, and i also not sure what proper question i should ask, so pardon me :D

what im trying to do is:

- i got a table, i get the value from mysql and paste it into the table through a LOOP
- for each row i give it a button (edit button)
- i give each button the id of value through a variable $id (eg. 1 2 3 4 )

my question is how can i get the specify button that i press by $_POST? i tried every way i could think of but it not work ( in my code below i warp the id with another variable=asdf so that it static but i can only get the last value of the id)

```
$viewvalue = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
<?php if (count($viewvalue) > 0): ?>
            <table id="t01">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($viewvalue))); ?></th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                  <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($viewvalue as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row);?></td>
                  <td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="<?php $a=$row['id']; $$a='asdf'; echo $$a; ?>" value="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php 
                if(isset($_POST['asdf'])){
                    echo $a;
                }
            ?>
```

i know theres a way to use jquery and ajax but sadly i cant get it to work, is it a way to do it with php alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll offer to replace this row:

```
<td><input type="submit" class="edit" name="<?php $a=$row['id']; $$a='asdf'; echo $$a; ?>" value="Edit" /></td>
```

by:

```
<td><button class="edit" name="act" value="<?php echo  $row['id'];?>">Edit</button></td>
```

after that you'll simply check the value of the $_POST['act']

Comment: thanks sir @-@ ur a life saver...i never though i can replace it in the value field...i just started learning web for a week and totally stuck in here